# Return the index for a list from a list in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang, indexof

I've been practicing using recursion to define the index in Erlang. Here I need to implement a function to return the index for a list from a list.

eg.

([2, 4, 4], [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4 ]) ----> 2

([1, 3], [5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5])     ----> 4

([1], [3, 2, a, {1, 1}, 1] ---->  4

Here is my code:

```
-module(project).
-export([index/2]).
index([X|XS],[_]) -> index([X|XS],[_],1).
index(_,[],_) -> [];
index([X|XS],[X|_], ACC) -> ACC;
index([X|XS],[_|rest],ACC) ->index([X|XS],rest,ACC+1).
```

I modified and coded logically but it still can not being compiled. I hope someone who can help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, list indices in Erlang tend to start with conventional 1, whereas array indices start with the traditional 0. Also, is this for practical application, or just practice?

Comment: @zxq9 I'm learning erlang. This was theoretically practicing and I appreciate your revised code for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, here is an implementation that is not written a very clean way, but illustrates the techniques I think you are looking for. Note there are two basic states: "checking" and "matching".

```
-module(sublistmatch).
-export([check/2]).

check(Segment, List) ->
    SegLen = length(Segment),
    ListLen = length(List),
    Index = 1,
    check(Segment, List, SegLen, ListLen, Index).

check(S, S, _, _, I) ->
    {ok, I};
check(_, _, SL, LL, _) when SL >= LL ->
    nomatch;
check(S = [H|Ss], [H|Ls], SL, LL, I) ->
    case matches(Ss, Ls) of
        true  -> {ok, I};
        false -> check(S, Ls, SL, LL - 1, I + 1)
    end;
check(S, [_|L], SL, LL, I) ->
    check(S, L, SL, LL - 1, I + 1).

matches([H|S], [H|L]) -> matches(S, L);
matches([], _)        -> true;
matches(_, _)         -> false.
```

Note that this depends on knowing the lengths of both the segment you are checking for, and the current length of the remaining list to check. Consider why this is necessary. Also consider how using the utility function `matches/2` gives us a natural place to explore whether an option matches, and backtracks if it does not.

In real programs you would use the standard library functions such as [`lists:prefix/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#prefix-2), [`lists:suffix/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#suffix-2), or [`sets:is_subset/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html#is_subset-2), or maybe some key or member operation over a gb_tree, dict, map or array depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

To Compile the code you have to change it to:

```
-module(project).
-export([index/2]).
%%index([X|XS],[_]) -> index([X|XS],[_],1).
index([X|XS],List) -> index([X|XS],List,1).
%% you shuld not pass '_' as parameter it's will be marked as unbound
index(_,[],_) -> [];

index([X|XS],[X|_], ACC) -> ACC;

%%index([X|XS],[_|rest],ACC) ->index([X|XS],rest,ACC+1).
index([X|XS],[_|Rest],ACC) ->index([X|XS],Rest,ACC+1).
%% rest is an atom, it's not the case you need to use here. 
%%Variables should start with upper case letter.
```

This code will compiled but wrong results as some cases.